# How to set tls version in Django database settings

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, ssl, tls1.2

I have an application deployed on azure, with the new releases I want to increase minimum tls version to 1.2

Python version 3.8
production MySQL version is 8.0.15

When we increase it from the mysql server app crashes and gives us the following error. Also I have other node applications that can successfully connect to my MySQL server with minimum TLS version configured to 1.2. I am looking for a way to config my application so that it starts using TLSv1.2

[exception when mysql server increases the minimum tls version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h93m1.png)

Here is my database connection settings

```
    DATABASES[database_name] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': database_name,
    'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
    'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
    'OPTIONS': {
        'ssl': {'ssl-ca': 'configs/public-azure-mysql-certificate.pem'}
    }
```

I tried adding an additional field like this under the 'ssl' option field like this

```
import ssl
```

later in the code

```
DATABASES[database_name] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': database_name,
    'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
    'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
    'OPTIONS': {
        'ssl': {'ssl-ca': 'configs/public-azure-mysql-certificate.pem', 'ssl-version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2}
    }
```

it gives the same error as well, How can I set the TLS version to 1.2 so that I can set mysql server to accept minimum TLSv1.2 ?

Thanks!

Comment: what web server are you using? If you're using nginx, then edit the config file for your domain that's where you can control tla version.

Comment: I don't use nginx. I deploy my application inside azure app service.

Comment: in that case you should make sure you have checked everything covered in this article that applies to your tech stack: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment?tabs=azure-monitor

Comment: @fkay my other applications can connect to my mysql server only my django application does not connect. I assume it's about django

Comment: in that case, the only other  thing I can think of is check if all your Django project dependencies are up to date too.